# Silverlight SelectedIndex not Databinding Correctly

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, silverlight-4.0, mvvm, combobox

I have unique behavior that I want to do.

I have a combobox that is databound to list of viewmodel items.  The first item is "[ Select Item ]".  The expected behavior is, as the user selects an item, I will do something, then reset the index back to the first item.

This works, except for the fact that if you want to select the 3rd item, 2 times in a row. Here is code:
ItemViewModel:

```
// NOTE, I have all the INotify goo actually implemented, this is the shorthand
// without goo to make it more readable.
public class ItemViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public string Caption { get; set; }
  public string Test { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel: (all my properties call OnPropertyChanged in the set as appropriate)

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> ChildItems { get; set; }
  public int SelectedChildIndex { get; set; }
  public string DebugOutText { get; set; }

  public ViewModel()
  {
    ChildItems = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>();
    SelectedChildIndex = -1;
    DebugOutText = string.Empty;
  }
  public void LoadChildItems()
  {
    ChildItems.Add(new ItemViewModel { Caption = "[ Select Item ]" });
    ChildItems.Add(new ItemViewModel { Caption = "One", Test = "Item 1" });
    ChildItems.Add(new ItemViewModel { Caption = "Two", Test = "Item 2" });
    ChildItems.Add(new ItemViewModel { Caption = "Three", Test = "Item 3" });
    SelectedChildIndex = 0;
  }
  private void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
  {
    if (propName == "SelectedChildIndex") { this.OnSelectedChildIndexChanged(); }
    if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
    { this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName)); }
  }
  public void OnSelectedChildIndexChanged()
  {
    if (SelectedChildIndex <= 0) return;
    DebugOutText += "\r\n" + ChildItems[SelectedChildIndex].Test;
    SelectedChildIndex = 0; // <- BIG ISSUE HERE
  }
}
```

Now my xaml:

```
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left">
  <ComboBox Width="200" x:Name="combo"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ChildItems}"
            SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=SelectedChildIndex, Mode=TwoWay}"
            DisplayMemberPath="Caption" />
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DebugOutText}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Finally my App Startup:

```
var vm = new ViewModel();
vm.LoadChildItems();
this.RootVisual = new MainPage { DataContext = vm };
```

Repo steps are:

- Run it
- Select the combo and click/select "Two".
- Now, click the combo. The visual style will show that "Two" is highlighted ("[ Select Item ]" should be highlighted). If you click/select on "Two", nothing will happen.

I've gone and put some trace code, the combo's SelectedIndex is 0, the ViewModel.SelectedChildIndex is 0, but the combo's SelectionChanged will not fire, unless I select something else.

I'm not really sure how to get it to work. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to admit I have my doubts about to the usability of the behaviour you want.  Nonetheless, if you have to use a combobox for this purpose, try replacing the line

```
    SelectedChildIndex = 0;
```

with

```
    Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => SelectedChildIndex = 0);
```

Comment: that was it. Thanks. The actual intent is to have code snippets be selected and automatically inserted into the body of text, saves clicks to not have an extra button to do the insert. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Going to take a wild guess here.  :)

```
// NOTE, I have all the INotify goo actually implemented, this is the shorthand 
// without goo to make it more readable.
```

You do not show your implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged.  Most implementations do something like:

```
public int SelectedChildIndex 
{
    get
    {
        return _selectedChildIndex;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value == _selectedChildIndex) return;
        _selectedChildIndex= value;
        OnProperyChanged("SelectedChildIndex ");
    }
}
```

Which short circuits the notification if the property value doesn't change.  If your code looks like this, take out the "if" statement and see if that fixes it.

Comment: I don't think this solves the problem.  I took Andre's code, implemented the 'INotify goo' without using such `if` statements and it behaved exactly as Andre described.

Comment: @phil I did have my code with the if, I removed it, and it did not work. Thanks for the suggestion though.